# How to find out what a key sequence really does

Tags: keymap, hooks

From time to time I observe unexpected behavior when editing text.  My first recourse is usually to use `C-h k` to find out what functions are being called by a given key sequence.  However, sometimes the documentation is at odds with the observed behavior.  In these cases, I usually assume that some other package has hooked into that function or key sequence and is modifying its behavior.

**How can I find out** ***which*** **functions are hooking into my key sequence?**

One example that I encountered recently was that I pressed the <kbd>"</kbd> key and quotation marks were inserted at the beginning and end of the active region.  I had a suspicion that this was not the default Emacs behavior, so I used `C-h k "` to find out what function was actually being called.

The `describe-key` documentation told me that the function `self-insert-command` was being called, which is a built-in function.  To make a long story short, after some amount of trial and error, I was able to determine that the behavior was caused by `electric-pair-mode`.  In the future, is there a faster way to arrive at this conclusion than to turn off suspected packages one at a time until finding the culprit?

Comment: Is it possible that the `electric-pair-mode` was activated in only some major modes? Do you still see `self-insert-command` for `"` when you do `C-h k` while `electric-pair-mode` is active?

Comment: @kaushalmodi: It turns out that `electric-pair-mode` works by hooking into `post-self-insert-hook`, and not by changing the keybinding.

Comment: `C-h k` tells you exactly what happens for a keypress. If you look at the documentation for `self-insert-command`, it very clearly says `post-self-insert-hook` is run after the command finishes.

Comment: @shosti: In this simple example, yes.  But what if what if an extension uses `after-change-functions` like Jordon mentions in his answer?  The documentation for a function probably won't specifically mention that hook, will it?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. `C-h k` + the standard hooks == the complete behavior (more or less). Of course sometimes that leaves a lot of possibilities, but it's still a lot more transparent than any other complex software system I know of.

Comment: @shosti: My question is not meant to be a complaint. Until Jordon's answer I did not even know that there was a list of "standard hooks" that I could check, hence my question.

Comment: This is a *failing in the design* of `electric-pair-mode`, IMO. A user should **not** need to investigate `post-self-insert-hook` - which was added recently (Emacs 24), BTW, in order to fudge stuff for `electric-pair-mode` (IIRC). `C-h k` should tell users what they need to know about what a key does, without making them chase around Robinson's barn to follow things like `post-self-insert-hook`. (Just one opinion.)

Comment: @Drew: I can't say I agree. The alternative is to override all the "pairing" keys, but what if another mode also wants to do something special with those keys, should it override them as well? Hooks are more modular and scale nicely to multiple minor modes.

Comment: @shosti: I have nothing against hooks. And yes, the same problem exists for things like `delete-selection-mode`. I don't have a good solution, I'm afraid. And it is at least good that the doc for `self-insert-command` mentions the hook, so users can track this down. Still, it is a far cry from `C-h k` telling you just what the behavior is, directly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no easy way to know exactly what a single key press will do.

If you see additional behavior always check the common hooks. See the list here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html

In most cases the important ones are:

- after-change-functions
- before-change-functions
- first-change-hook
- post-command-hook
- pre-command-hook
- post-self-insert-hook

You'll need to inspect those hooks and look into the functions they contain to see which one is modifying your behavior.

If the functions in these hooks don't fully describe the observed behavior, check the functions for advice which will show up in their documentation from `describe-function`.

---

*Edit:
I've written some functions to help describe a hook better than going through the functions one by one: https://gist.github.com/jordonbiondo/bad03e44bb053db0f1eb
You can use `describe-hook` defined there like the other describe functions. Here is a sample of it's output:*

[image]

And here's all the code, in case the gist disappears:

```lisp
(defun guess-all-hooks ()
  "Return a list of all variables that are probably hook lists."
  (let ((syms '()))
    (mapatoms
     (lambda (sym)
       (if (ignore-errors (symbol-value sym))
           (let ((name (symbol-name sym)))
             (when (string-match "-\\(hook[s]?\\|functions\\)$" name)
               (push sym syms))))))
    syms))

(defun face-it (str face)
  "Apply FACE to STR and return."
  (propertize str 'face face))

(defun describe-hook (hook)
  "Display documentation about a hook variable and the
functions it contains."
  (interactive
   (list (completing-read
          "Hook: " (mapcar (lambda (x) (cons x nil)) (guess-all-hooks)))))
  (let* ((sym (intern hook))
         (sym-doc (documentation-property sym 'variable-documentation))
         (hook-docs (mapcar
                     (lambda (func)
                       (cons func (ignore-errors (documentation func))))
                     (symbol-value sym))))
    (switch-to-buffer
     (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*describe-hook*")
       (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
         (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
         (insert (face-it "Hook: " 'font-lock-constant-face) "\n\n")
         (insert (face-it (concat "`" hook "'") 'font-lock-variable-name-face))
         (replace-string "\n" "\n\t" nil
                         (point)
                         (save-excursion
                           (insert "\n" sym-doc "\n\n")
                           (1- (point))))
         (goto-char (point-max))
         (insert (face-it "Hook Functions: " 'font-lock-constant-face) "\n\n")
         (dolist (hd hook-docs)
           (insert (face-it (concat "`" (symbol-name (car hd)) "'")
                            'font-lock-function-name-face)
                   ": \n\t")
           (replace-string "\n" "\n\t" nil
                           (point)
                           (save-excursion
                             (insert (or (cdr hd) "No Documentation") "\n\n")
                             (1- (point))))
           (goto-char (point-max))))
       (help-mode)
       (help-make-xrefs)
       (read-only-mode t)
       (setq truncate-lines nil)
       (current-buffer)))))
```

Comment: Does that mean that when a function gets advised, the documentation is automatically updated to reflect the change?

Comment: I do no know if the actual properties get updated, but the value returned by `documentation` is updated to reflect.

Comment: @nispio yes, it is.

Comment: The code/function in  https://gist.github.com/jordonbiondo/bad03e44bb053db0f1eb could, and in my opinion, should, be included in the answer. I think a SE answer has a limit of 30,000 characters.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not a full answer to your question, but the package  [`helm-descbinds`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-descbinds) helps you **search** all the defined keyboard bindings from the ascii representation of the shortcut. For every hit, it shows you the interactive function associated with the keyboard shortcut, and you can ask `helm-descbinds` to **describe** it, or **execute** it directly from the search results.

[image]

Here is the package description from the GitHub site:

> Helm Descbinds provides an interface to emacs’ describe-bindings
>   making the currently active key bindings interactively searchable with
>   helm.
>
> Additionally you have the following actions
>
> - Execute the command
> - Describe the command
> - Find the command
>
> And `C-z` will give you a persistent description of the current command.

Comment: This is great.  I will definitely bind this to `C-h b`.  My only wish is that I could jump to the item on the list by entering the actual key sequence instead of typing out `C` `-` `c` `_` `C` `-` `p`